# Can I say: one route number traverse with many buses with the same number!

Tags: meaning-in-context

For example there is many buses with the same number drive the same route so can I say, so can I use traverse like this:

"one route number traverses with many buses with the same number!"

Comment: Attempting to keep as close to your formulation as possible, one might say, "One numbered route **is traversed by** many buses with the same number."  But I'd probably completely rewrite it as: "A single route is served by many buses, each with the same number."

Comment: I agree with Jim. The use of traverse seems odd here.

Comment: It sounds like an exercise: make a sentence with the verb _traverse_. In that case, the selected sentence is indeed unfortunate. Buses traverse the city, but route numbers do not traverse anything.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

All of the buses that serve that route have the same number.